# How to filter date columns in Mysql database effectively?

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have a column called created_at and its datatype is (date).
Consider the following two SQL queries.

```
select * from my_table where created_at < '2019-11-05'
```

and the other one is

```
 select * from my_table where created_at < date('2019-11-05')
```

which query is right and should I use in the future date comparisons?

Comment: It is the same query. Wrapping into DATE() function in 2nd query is excess. See user manual about date literals.

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for both and see what the database perceives as the difference. Obviously the number of rows and an index on the relevant column would be important. If you're storing `DATE`s, then store them as, err..., well..., `DATE`s and **not** `VARCHAR`s. Storing them as such can and probably will confuse the optimiser - always use the appropriate datatype for whatever you're storing.

Comment: Watch out! If your column is a DateTime but you filter on the Date, then you're gonna be ignoring the time component - you'll effectively get incorrect results.